# Spring Cloud DataFlow documentation has missing sections

Tags: spring, spring-xd, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am reading right now the Spring Cloud DataFlow documentation, but it turn out that the sections contained in PART IV (Modules) has some kind of error, because the whole section is fill up with this kind of text

Unresolved directive in raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-modules/master/
spring-cloud-stream-modules-docs/src/main/asciidoc/sinks.adoc - include::{repo-root}/cassandra-sink/
README.adoc[tags=ref-doc]

There is any way to access to this documentation?

Is Spring XD Documentation Module section a sustitution for my problem?, Spring Cloud DataFlow modules work the same way that Spring XD, so I can use Spring XD documentation instead?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

We are getting ready for the M3 release of Spring Cloud Data Flow and the docs are actively being restructured right now. We will get this cleaned up very soon.

In the meantime, please feel to review each application level READMEs from the app-starter [repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/apps). Here's an example for [cassandra-sink](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/cassandra/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-cassandra).